# Android : "No eligible devices for app install" error while downloading GPS based app

Tags: android, gps

GPS based android app is not installing in Assisted-GPS (A-GPS) based android device.
Error states that "No eligible devices for app install"

Device specification is as follows,

Model : Lenovo A369i

Android OS Ver : 4.2.2

Comment: seems like u dont hav gps on that device so the developer bound for the devices which does not hav gps in google play

Comment: @Ali4Android : I agree, That Lenovo device have an A-GPS support, doesn't have GPS. But I have developed the app which is based on GPS, Now I am trying to install on A-GPS supported devices, it states the above error. Any solution or any rework in code?

Comment: remove unnesesary permissions from manifest or post the permission u are using in manifest